# Compile Error: Field expression not allowed for generic SObject at line 33 column 69

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-chatter

I am trying to write a generic controller which will work for several different object types, but when I try to access custom fields from those objects, I get the following error:

> Compile Error: Field expression not allowed for generic SObject at line 33 column 69

Here's my generic controller code:

```
public with sharing class PhotoUploadController {

    public Attachment objAttach{get;set;}
    public sObject sobj{get;set;}
    public string ObjectName {get;set;}
    public Decimal Height{get;set;}
    public Decimal Width {get;set;}
    Public List<Attachment> lstAttachment {get;set;}

     public String setObjectType(sObject newObj)
      {
        this.ObjectName = newObj.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
        return(this.ObjectName );
       }

    public String getObjectType() 
    {
          return(this.ObjectName);  
     }

   public PhotoUploadController (ApexPages.StandardController controller)
     {

        objAttach=new Attachment();
        lstAttachment= new List<Attachment>();
        sobj = controller.getRecord();
        if(sobj.id!=null){
           sobj = Database.query('select id,name,Image_Attachment_ID__c from ObjectName where id=:sobj.id');  
        } 

         if(sobj.Image_Attachment_ID__c!=null){

            lstattachment=[SELECT id,body from Attachment where Id=:sobj.Image_Attachment_ID__c limit 1];
            if(lstattachment.size()>0)
            {
                objAttach=lstattachment[0];
            }
        }         
    }

    public pageReference savePhoto(){  
     sobj.HeightOfPhoto__c=Height;
     sobj.WidthOfPhoto__c=Width;

        try {
            if (!Schema.sObjectType.sobjectName.isUpdateable())
                {
                  return null;
                }
            String contentType;

            if(objAttach.ContentType !=null){
               contentType=objAttach.ContentType;
            }

            if(contentType !=null && (contentType == 'image/jpeg' || contentType == 'image/CR2' || contentType== 'image/jpg' || contentType== 'image/png' || contentType== 'image/bmp' || contentType== 'image/gif')){            
            //objAttach.body=body;
            //objAttach.name=name;
            if(objAttach.body!=null && objAttach.name!=null && sobj.id !=null){
                 If(objAttach.Id==null)
                     objAttach.parentId=sobj.id;
                 if(!Schema.sObjectType.Attachment.isUpdateable()){
                  return null;
                  }

                 try{
                        upsert objAttach;
                        sobj.Image_URL__c=URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+objAttach.id;
                        sobj.Image_Attachment_ID__c= objAttach.id;
                        objAttach =null;
                        if (!Schema.sObjectType.ObjectName.isUpdateable()){
                          return null;
                        }
                       upsert sobj;
                   }
                   catch (DMLException e) {
                           if(e.getMessage().contains('STORAGE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED')){
                              ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Your orgnization Storage Limit has been exceeded, Please contact your Administrator.'));
                           }else{
                             ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error uploading attachment'));
                           }
                           return null;
                    }finally {
                          objAttach = new Attachment();
                    }    
            }

         }
         else{
              objAttach = new Attachment();
              ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Please, Upload image file with extension .JPG .JPEG .BMP .PNG or .GIF'));
              return null;
         }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {            
             return null;
        }
        return new pagereference('/'+sobj.id);    
    }

}
```

Can someone explain this error message in a bit more detail? How do I access the fields I need from a generic SObject type?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple issues in your code, but the cause of the reported error message is this snippet:

```
sobj.Image_Attachment_ID__c
```

You've not specified what type of SObject you are expecting, so there is no way to know:

1. If the SObject in memory even *has* that field
2. What type of field it is
3. What metadata belongs with that field (if the field was a picklist, you may have several SObjects with the same field name, but with different picklist options, etc)

The [get(fieldName)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_get) function may be useful to you in this scenario. You may end up with an exception (which you can catch) if the SObject doesn't have that field, and it's up to you to cast the value into the proper data type (since it'll only return an object), which could throw a casting error if the value is a datetime and you try to cast it to an Id, etc.

Another issue I spotted:

`[SELECT id,body from Attachment where Id=:sobj.Image_Attachment_ID__c limit 1]` will never return a value. I think you meant `ParentId=:sobj.Image_Attachment_ID__c`.